# Pulling value from alt tag - need it to change on click Jquery

Tags: jquery, attributes, tags, alt

Ok - so I've made a little image gallery - basically when you click a thumbnail, it pulls in the title from the alt tag - puts it in a div to display below the image as the title,  and displays the image as a fullscreen bg

What I'm trying to do is have this title display when the page loads - and when you click, remove the existing value and replace it with the new one

Currently the title isn't displaying on page load, when you click it - it shows the title as desired, but when you click another image it doesn't remove this title

Heres my existing code

```
    <ul id="horses">
                <li><a class="clicker" rel="drawings-bg"><img src="/assets/img/portfolio/horse.jpg" alt="horse" /></a></li>
                <li><a class="clicker" rel="contact-bg"><img src="/assets/img/portfolio/dogs.jpg" alt="dogs" /></a></li>
                <li><a class="clicker" rel="drawings-bg"><img src="/assets/img/portfolio/horse.jpg" alt="horse" /></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Jquery

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
    var imginfo = $('.imgtitle');
$("ul#horses li img").click(function() {
      if(imginfo)  $(imginfo).siblings('.imgtitle').remove();
$(this).parent().append("<div class=imgtitle>" + $(this).attr("alt") + "</div>");
     });
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: is it normal that your imginfo var has a selector for a class that has not been assigned to any element? i dont see any elements with a class called imgtitle

Comment: And what's happening instead? Do you get an error? Nothing? Waldo appearing out of nowhere on your page in his little hat?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you want to display in the title?

Comment: yeah waldo scared me s**tless when he popped up - it loads the alt tag on click but when you click another image it doesn't remove it - also doesn't show on page load

Comment: @AntiFaith: The not removing previous ones I've addressed in my answer. There's nothing in your code that would make a title appear on page load.

Comment: sorry - I've been messing around with it so much I've un-done to the wrong point lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of it seems to work:

This line has a problem:

```
if(imginfo)  $(imginfo).siblings('.imgtitle').remove();
```

jQuery instances are always truthy, so that line will always run. Ignoring that, though, shouldn't it be more like this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var imginfo = $('.imgtitle');
  $("ul#horses li img").click(function() {
    $('ul#horses li .imgtitle').remove();
    $(this).parent().append(
      "<div class=imgtitle>" + $(this).attr("alt") + "</div>"
    );
  });
});
```

...if you're trying to remove the other titles when displaying a new one: http://jsbin.com/iqugih

Comment: cheers for the heads up - still have the same issue though - not loading on page load, and not removing when you click another element

Comment: sigh - having an issue getting it to start on page load now - massive headache atm, finishing a one day build for client - any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$("ul#horses li img").click(function() {
    var i = $(this);
    var imageTitle = i.parent().find('.imgtitle');
    if(null === imageTitle || imageTitle.length == 0) {
        imageTitle = $('<div/>').addClass('imgtitle');
        i.parent().append(imageTitle);
    }

    imageTitle.html(i.attr('alt'));
});
```

Comment: it works, but it's working the same as I currently have - doesn't display the title on page load - and when you click it isn't removing the previous title